# Can I avoid typing feature:repo-add camel 2.17.3 and have the features.xml file make this happen automatically?

Tags: apache-karaf, karaf

In Apache Karaf, before I install my features.xml file I need to type.

```
feature:repo-add camel 2.17.3
```

Is there any way to express in the features.xml file some command which makes this occur ? So that I can avoid typing it on the command line inside Karaf.

The motivation for this question is that it is nice that generally when I add a features.xml file to the deploy directory of Karaf that it can pull down all the dependent bundles by itself automatically. I like the fact that it has this automatic feature and the only thing I need to send is the features.xml. So this leads to my desire to encapsulate all the work in the features.xml file so that I do not need to type anything into the Karaf console.

Comment: Do you mean when simply installing camel features or when installing your own feature file which needs camel features?

Comment: I mean that I hope the features.xml file can do everything when I drop it into the deploy directory, can that occur? I don't want to have to do the manual process of typing it into the console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works. You need to refer to the camel feature xml using the repository tag. 
See the [cxf-dosgi samples feature xml](https://github.com/apache/cxf-dosgi/blob/master/samples/features/src/main/resources/features.xml).

The repository xml tag must appear within the features XML tag. So its like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<features xmlns="http://karaf.apache.org/xmlns/features/v1.3.0" name="jump_micro">
    <repository>mvn:org.apache.camel.karaf/apache-camel/2.17.3/xml/features</repository>
    <feature description="jump_micro" version="1.0.0" name="jump_micro">
...
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a shortcut for feature:repo-add mvn:org.apache.camel.karaf/apache-camel/2.17.3/xml/features
so no, this can't really be skipped as you somehow need to tell which feature file to use. If you skip the version it'll be that latest available version.